# Error on reading file using spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I have an error reading a local file in apache spark.
    scala> val f=sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/Downloads/sample.txt")

```
f: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/cloudera/Downloads/sample.txt MapPartitionsRDD[9] at textFile at <console>:27
```

**scala> f.count()**

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist:
>   hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/Downloads/sample.txt    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1959)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:30)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:35)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:37)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:39)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:41)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:43)   at $iwC$$iwC.(:45)
>     at $iwC.(:47)    at (:49)     at
>   .(:53)     at .()     at
>   .(:7)  at .()     at $print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:35)  at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the file path. The path need to be specified when you have hadoop path set.

```
sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Downloads/sample.txt")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: scala> f.count()
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]17/05/30 02:38:26 WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

17/05/30 02:39:16 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down

Comment: are you trying to run on local or yarn ?

Comment: here is nice article about it https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting